# Не работает exec()

Tags: php, windows, exec

Пытаюсь запустить *.cmd из скрипта, но ничего не выходит. Командник не запускается. Делаю я это следующим образом:

```
$command = "//BLDSITEVM/www/html/test_b.ru/www/opr/admin/store/cls_symstore.cmd"; 
exec($command);
```

В чем моя ошибка?
PHP не виснет. Просто не вызывается командник.

Comment: Даже в логи ничего не выводится. Путь правильный. Запускается нужный командник. Запускаю теперь так: `$system = ('start\start.cmd 1 > error.log');
$command = exec($system);`

Comment: То есть, командник запустился, но процесс висит и ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызывается у меня командник таким образом:

```
exec("cls_symstore.cmd");
```

Всё отлично работает. Проблема была в том, что для выполнения самого командника мне нужен был WinDbg на сервере.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте в [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.phpinfo.php) разрешение на использование этой команды. По умолчанию команда [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php) заблокирована из-за соображений безопасности.

Зайдите в `php.ini` и уберите у параметра `disable_functions` нужные вам функции.

Comment: Да. Я проверяла. Запретов никаких нет. Поэтому я и решила, что делаю что-то не так. Может путь так нельзя задавать?

Comment: Ещё я попробовала так его запустить: `$system = ('start\cls_symstore.cmd');
$command = exec($system); ` Но теперь процесс висит и ничего не происходит.(

Comment: @Юленька если процесс стартует, может быть дело в самом cmd? От руки он нормально запускается?

Comment: Да. От руки запускается отлично. Пользуются им уже давно. Я даже создала отдельный start.cmd куда поместила только `echo Hello world!` но он тоже запускается и висит в процессах. В лог опять ничего не выводится. Напасть какая-то.

Comment: А ещё просто опробовала `echo exec("whoami");` и получила: nt authority\system Т.е., вроде бы функция должна работать.

Comment: Командник с "Hello world!" отработал по такой схеме: `exec("start.cmd > error.log");` Хм... может для запуска cls_symstore.cmd я что-то не так делаю...

Comment: @Юленька посмотрите, что возвращает команда, у неё за вывод отвечает вторая переменная,

Comment: Спасибо за советы. Оказалось проблема совсем не в вызове командника.) Бревна не заметила.))